# preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 11 in Laravel Slug

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

i'm building an Arabic Slug system form my Blog App

when i add a new Slug i got this error

> preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 11

controller

```
public function slug($string, $separator = '-') {
    if (is_null($string)) {
        return "";
    }

    $string = trim($string);

    $string = mb_strtolower($string, "UTF-8");;

    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-ءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]#u/", "", $string);

    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);

    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", $separator, $string);

    return $string;
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'title'         => 'required|max:255',
        'slug'          => 'required|min:3|max:255|unique:posts',
        'body'          => 'required',
    ));
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->slug = $this->slug($request->slug);
    $post->body = $request->input('body');


    $post->save();

    return redirect('admin/posts')->with('success', 'post is successfully saved');
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('post/{slug}', 'PagesController@post')->name('post.show');
```

Comment: At the end, `#u/` shouldn't be `#/u`?

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a extra `-` after `\s`.

Replace:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-ءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]#u/", "", $string);
```

with

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\sءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]#u/", "", $string);
```

Or fix it to match your regex, like escaping it `\-`.